# Fast sine and cosine function in java

Tags: java, optimization, trigonometry

I know about the `Math.sin()` and `Math.cos()` functions, but I'm wondering if there's a way I can create (or use an already-existing) a faster function, given that I don't care about pinpoint accuracy. I'm looking to execute a basic sin or cos calculation, and have it perform essentially as fast as possible. Would simply iterating the sigma a few times be any faster than `Math.sin()`?

Comment: You could precalculate the values you require. that would be the fastest.

Comment: Usually, JDK library functions contain the best practice implementations for a given problem statements. I would recommend you to use Math class unless you really really need the performance in case of building a real time app.

Comment: In addition to the suggestions already given, you could also utilize [small-angle approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation), and implement some basic logic to convert larger angles into smaller complements so that the approximation could be used in most (if not all) cases -- assuming your precision requirements are as relaxed as you suggest.

Answer (score 7):

Since you don't care much about accuracy store it in a table that is precomputed or only computed once, this is what I do when I want to avoid calls to `Math` which can be expensive when done alot.

Roughly

```
public class CosSineTable {
double[] cos = new double[361];
double[] sin = new double[361];
private static CosSineTable table = new CosSineTable();

private CosSineTable() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i++) {
        cos[i] = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i));
        sin[i] = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i));
    }
}

public double getSine(int angle) {
    int angleCircle = angle % 360;
    return sin[angleCircle];
}

public double getCos(int angle) {
    int angleCircle = angle % 360;
    return cos[angleCircle];
}

public static CosSineTable getTable() {
    return table;
}
}
```

I leave the optimization of the loop and methods to you.

Comment: I like this plan, but it won't work for negative angles as is.  `%` isn't modulo in the mathematical sense, but rather the remainder. Easily fixed, though.

Comment: Aye just need to return -sin[angle] for negatives, cos is the same.

Comment: Any reason why your arrays are 361 long instead of 360? As it's been almost 10 years I'm sure you know, but for junior readers: Index 360 is not needed since `x % 360` never gives 360, at most 359.

Answer (score 7):

A pre-calculated table's the way to go. Here's an implementation:

```
static final int precision = 100; // gradations per degree, adjust to suit

static final int modulus = 360*precision;
static final float[] sin = new float[modulus]; // lookup table
static { 
    // a static initializer fills the table
    // in this implementation, units are in degrees
    for (int i = 0; i<sin.length; i++) {
        sin[i]=(float)Math.sin((i*Math.PI)/(precision*180));
    }
}
// Private function for table lookup
private static float sinLookup(int a) {
    return a>=0 ? sin[a%(modulus)] : -sin[-a%(modulus)];
}

// These are your working functions:
public static float sin(float a) {
    return sinLookup((int)(a * precision + 0.5f));
}
public static float cos(float a) {
    return sinLookup((int)((a+90f) * precision + 0.5f));
}
```

On my laptop, these were about 6x faster than `Math.sin`.

I only used one table -- the cost of shifting a cosine into a sine wasn't really discernible.

I used floats, assuming that's what you'll likely use in your calculations, given your preference for performance over precision. It doesn't make much difference here, since the bottleneck is really just the array lookup.

Here are my benchmarks:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int reps = 1<<23;
    int sets = 4;

    Q.pl("  Trial  sinTab  cosTab  sinLib");
    for(int i = 0; i<sets; i++) {
        Q.pf("%7d\t%7.2f\t%7.2f\t%7.2f\n", i, testSinTab(reps), testCosTab(reps), testSinLib(reps));
    }
}

private static float[] sample(int n) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    float[] values = new float[n];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        values[i] = 400*(rand.nextFloat()*2-1);
    }
    return values;
}
private static float testSinTab(int n) {
    float[] sample = sample(n);
    long time = -System.nanoTime();
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        sample[i] = sin(sample[i]);
    }
    time += System.nanoTime();
    return (time/1e6f);
}
private static float testCosTab(int n) {
    float[] sample = sample(n);
    long time = -System.nanoTime();
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        sample[i] = cos(sample[i]);
    }
    time += System.nanoTime();
    return time/1e6f;
}
private static float testSinLib(int n) {
    float[] sample = sample(n);
    long time = -System.nanoTime();
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        sample[i] = (float) Math.sin(sample[i]);
    }
    time += System.nanoTime();
    return time/1e6f;
}
```

output:

```
  Trial  sinTab  cosTab  sinLib
      0  102.51  111.19  596.57
      1   93.72   92.20  578.22
      2  100.06  107.20  600.68
      3  103.65  102.67  629.86
```

Comment: LUT benchmarks will be fast since they can use the CPU cache. FWIW, LUTs can wreck havoc on the CPU cache for real world application usage.

Answer (score 2):

You can try
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jafama/

It uses look-up tables, so it might actually be slower
than Math, especially if the tables are often evicted from CPU cache,
but for thousands of successive calls it can be quite faster.

It also seems slower during class load (maybe the JIT doesn't kicks in then yet),
so you might want to avoid it in that particular use-case.

Comment: the OP has asked for a faster solution and not a slow one.

Comment: If one uses a tables of 17 sine/cosine pairs within an octant (272 bytes), a fourth-order polynomial approximation will suffice to achieve accuracy of about half a part per billion. Depending upon the size of the CPU cache and usage patterns, it may be helpful to expand that to 33 pairs for a quadrant [allowing the table to hold sine/cosine pairs in consecutive array slots without requiring them to be conditionally swapped], or even to use a `switch` statement to select one of 17 pairs of forumulas, or 33 formulas or pairs thereof (depending upon whether one wants just sin, just cos, or both).

Comment: A compromise would be to use 33 groups of five `double` values which would be used in polynomial approximations with the residue after selecting an quadrant, or 129 groups of five for a whole circle (avoiding conditional logic).  The larger table would take about 5K, which might be a problem for machines with small caches, but would replace four multiples with three consecutive-item fetches when computing sine alone, or eight multiplies with eight consecutive-item fetches when computing both.

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is old, but I think it's the fastest java implementation sintable with precision to 65536 elements.

```
public class MathHelper {

    private static double[] a = new double[65536];

    public static final double sin(float f) {
        return a[(int) (f * 10430.378F) & '\uffff'];
    }

    public static final double cos(float f) {
        return a[(int) (f * 10430.378F + 16384.0F) & '\uffff'];
    }

    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < 65536; ++i) {
            a[i] = Math.sin((double) i * 3.141592653589793D * 2.0D / 65536.0D);
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/Bukkit/mc-dev/blob/master/net/minecraft/server/MathHelper.java

Comment: No, it's not sadly. It's actually slow enough that it usually gets replaced when the game is modded (See: BetterFPS/Optifine, which both override it). That's Notch's implementation, and it's not all that good :P